# WooCommerce update version 3.0.x breaks site -

Tags: php, wordpress, class, woocommerce, product

I updated to WooCommerce version 3.0.x from version 2.6.x and my site strangely stops loading correctly.

I get the message:

> "**Object of class WC_Product_Variable could not be converted to string**"

the source of the error is a line in the [**woocommerce/includes/wc-product-functions.php**](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-product-functions.php) file

```
$value = ucwords( str_replace( '-', ' ', $value ) );
```

I was able to get the site working fine again by commenting out the block of code that incorporates the line, starting at "**`if ( taxonomy_exists( $name ) ) {`**", but I don't really feel comfortable with such a patchwork solution.

Could someone possibly explain the reason for this error?

Here is my code:

```
foreach ( $variation_attributes as $name => $value ) {
        if ( ! $value ) {
            continue;
        }

        // If this is a term slug, get the term's nice name
        /*if ( taxonomy_exists( $name ) ) {
            $term = get_term_by( 'slug', $value, $name );
            if ( ! is_wp_error( $term ) && ! empty( $term->name ) ) {
                $value = $term->name;
            }
        } else {
            $value = ucwords( str_replace( '-', ' ', $value ) );
        }

        if ( $include_names ) {
            if ( $flat ) {
                $variation_list[] = wc_attribute_label( $name, $product ) . ': ' . rawurldecode( $value );
            } else {
                $variation_list[] = '<dt>' . wc_attribute_label( $name, $product ) . ':</dt><dd>' . rawurldecode( $value ) . '</dd>';
            }
        } else {
            if ( $flat ) {
                $variation_list[] = rawurldecode( $value );
            } else {
                $variation_list[] = '<li>' . rawurldecode( $value ) . '</li>';
            }
        }*/
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that **`$value` is not a string** but an **object** or an **array** of value of values.

So using **`str_replace()`** PHP function can't work with it as it works on strings.

You should better try to use a **`foreach`** loop on it or **`implode()`** PHP function to convert it into a string, but…

> **The real problem location:**
>
> - Your active child theme (or theme) and `function.php` file where most of the time we put some custom code.
> - Third party plugins involved in WooCommerce
>
> WooCommerce version 3.0+ is a major release that is much more strict. A new syntax around getters and setters is now necessary to access to the objects in most WC Classes.

---

For reference:

- [WC_Product_Variable Class](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html)
- [WC_Product Class](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Abstract_Legacy_Product.html)

> Here is the **Legacy and deprecated functions** that are here to keep the **`WC_Abstract_Product`** clean (This class will be removed in future versions):

- [WC_Abstract_Legacy_Product](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Abstract_Legacy_Product.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Loric! I've been trying to use a foreach loop, with no success so far. How would I go about coding it in this scenario? Also, any idea why this error would come up in the first place? I've tried disabling all other woocommerce related plugins, to no avail.

Comment: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-product-functions.php - Here's a link to a github upload of the same file. The error starts at line 370 for me

Comment: Thanks again for the help Loic. The issue ultimately ended up being the change in the WC syntax like you said. I created a set of functions that alter my variable product prices based on user role, and it looks like syntax change interferes with it. It's a pretty complex file and took me quite a long time to code to begin with, so I ultimately decided to revert back to WC 2 instead of having to relearn everything. I'll perhaps revisit it later on with a test version of the site.